# Cannot find module Heroku CLI package.json

Tags: heroku

I'm on MacOS and installed the Heroku CLI a few months ago and ran into this error trying to use the command line tools today:

```
Error: Cannot find module '{user profile}/.local/share/heroku/client/6.15.25-635e5c6/package.json'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at run ({user profile}/.local/share/heroku/client/6.15.25-635e5c6/node_modules/@cli-engine/engine/lib/cli.js:82:22)
at Object.<anonymous> ({user profile}/.local/share/heroku/client/6.15.25-635e5c6/bin/heroku.js:7:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
```

I tried `brew uninstall heroku/brew/heroku` and then reinstalling with no change in the error.

Answer (score 5):

I found [this](https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/666) issue on GitHub that fixed it.

The fix is just delete `~/.local/share/heroku/client` and it worked fine again as normal.